# What are the guarantees provided for various lock implementations in Redisson?

Tags: redis, locking, redisson, distributed-lock

Redisson has several lock implementations ( `RLock`, `RedissonMultiLock`, `RedissonRedLock`), but what guarantees are provided in terms of safety and liveness for each of the lock types is not clear.

Referring to this - https://redis.io/topics/distlock I believe the RedLock implementation must be the most robust implementation, but nothing is mentioned regarding the lack of fault-tolerance wrt the other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Redisson lock objects have the same fault-tolerance property as Redis setup itself.